# event channelCreate .setauthor

Tags: discord.js

is there any way to put the user who created the channel in .setAuthor? I searched in https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel but found nothing

```
  client.on("channelCreate", function(channel) {
  const logchannel = channel.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === "logchannel")
  if (!logchannel) return

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("Channel created)
  .setDescription(`Channel <#${channel.id}> has created.`)
  .setTimestamp()
  .setAuthor(//user who created the channel)
  
  logchannel.send(embed)  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to use the [AuditLogs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildAuditLogs), you may want to take a look at it.